# Keycoak: Import realm when creating Docker container

Tags: docker, keycloak

I have the a docker-compose configuration for Keycloak and Postgres that works fine.
Now, I have exported the config in real-export.json in order to restart Keycloak with these configuration. Unfortunately, the Keycloak container does not work as expected.

Original docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - ~/docker/volumes/keycloak-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASS}
  keycloak:
      image: mihaibob/keycloak:14.0.0
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASS}
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASS}
        # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
        #JDBC_PARAMS: "ssl=true"
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

New docker-compose to import config:

```
version: '3.1'
services:

   postgres:
      image: postgres
      container_name: postgres
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASS}

   keycloak:
      image: mihaibob/keycloak:14.0.0
      volumes:
        - ./realm-export.json:/tmp/realm-export.json
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASS}
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASS}
        KEYCLOAK_MIGRATION_ACTION: IMPORT
        KEYCLOAK_IMPORT: /tmp/realm-export.json
        # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
        #JDBC_PARAMS: "ssl=true"
      ports:
        - 9080:8080
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

The Keycloak container terminates with the following logs:

```
OpenJDK Server VM warning: No monotonic clock was available - timed services may be adversely affected if the time-of-day clock changes


Added 'admin' to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json', restart server to load user


-b 0.0.0.0


=========================================================================



  Using PostgreSQL database



=========================================================================
```

Grateful for every idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute path for the volume mounting

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a better keycloak image vendor. I ended up, after using for sometime JBoss's one, by going with the **quay** version

here: https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers

It is straightforward to mount your volume that contains the json file of your realm and update the CMD with `--import-realm` option.